# Issue with building gradle project

Tags: gradle, rpm, gradlew

I am building a JAVA project with gradle but each time I am getting following error:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * Where: Build file '/data/project1/build.gradle' line: 3
 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'erpcrm'.
     > org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecImpl
```

line 3 of `build.gradle` is like this:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'rpm'
```

But I have installed gradle-rpm-plugin separately by downloading it from git and later doing ./gradlew build. Even after that above problem is coming.

Comment: Need to show more of your `build.gradle`. Is that the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use new version of gradle. The 'rpm' plugin is deprecated in newer version. You can try using the [ospackage plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.ospackage) from Netflix. I had the exact same problem when using a build file written against Gradle 1.x but my (new) machine had Gradle 3.x. The plugin upgrade solved it.

Of course, if you are using a very old gradle file, this upgrade might break many other things.